# How to read XML using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq, dataset

I have a program that queries a database, and reports the results.  Here is my query:

```
Select Service, Total
From Services
Where dtcreated between @startdate and @enddate
```

The dataset named `dataset` reports this to `reportviewer1`

I then have an xml file here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<config>
    <goals>
           <service1>4</service1>
           <service2>3</service2>
        </goals>
</config>
```

The xml (location `C:\config.xml` ) reports to `Reportviewer2`

What I'd like to do is email the results of the query, AND the value of the service goals from the xml file.  I am able to use LINQ to put together the table to be emailed from the dataset my code is below:

```
Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load("C:\Config.xml")
Dim employees As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()

    Dim test = _
    <html><body><table><tr><th>Service</th><th>Total Sold</th><th>Goals</th></tr>
        <%= From service In Me.Dataset.datatable.AsEnumerable _
            Select <tr><td><%= service.Service_Category.ToString %></td>
                       <td><%= service.Total_Sold.ToString %></td>
                       <%= From XMLFile In xelement.Descendants("goals").AsEnumerable _
                           Select <td><%= XMLFile.Descendants("goals").Value %></td> %></tr> %>
        </table></body></html>
```

Now what I'd like to do is include in the same table the values of the XML file to report in a 3rd column within the build of data above.  The third column as you can see I would like to be "Goals" and it should display 4, then 3 as per my config file.  How can I include the values of my xml file in the Linq and HTML build above?  Here is what my output currently looks like:

```
Service Total Sold  Goals
Service1       51   
Service2       12
```

As you can see i'm missing the "4" and "3" from the config file.

Here is what I want my output to look like:

```
Service Total Sold  Goals
Service1    51            4
Service2    12            3
```

Comment: Incidentally, I just mentioned inline XML in VB.NET... _OUCH!_ What's wrong with a template file resource?

Comment: Not sure I know how to use a template file resource and I would still have the same problem filling the table above with the info... Would I be able to edit the config file after build?  The goals will change monthly/yearly so I need a way to report the goals.  It's an automated program that will query the database, look at our goal settings, build the table and then send the table in an email.

Comment: @GrantThomas If there was one thing I wish I could use in tedious test-setups and asserts, it'd be inline XML, when I write my C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using Linq to XML with (hopefully an object already exists or you can create one), using linqpad to get the query down just right.

The code to get the xml document

```
            private static XDocument GetXmlDataFromFileName(string fileName)
            {
                // read the xml file into memory
                return XDocument.Load(new FileStream(String.Format(@"C:\<some path>\{0}.xml", fileName), FileMode.Open));
            }
```

Extension method to .Value so it trims the results not necessary, but I used it do to spaces at the end or if the value didn't exist an empty string.

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static String ValueTrim(this XElement element)
    {
        return element != null ? element.Value.Trim() : "";
    }
}
```

The code to read the xml data into an object

```
            // read the xml file into memory
            var doc = GetXmlDataFromFileName("FormsPersistence");
            var data = (from attrib in doc.Descendants("FormsPersistenceDs").Descendants("Properties")
                        select new FormsPersistence
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            FormName = attrib.Element("FormName").ValueTrim(),
                            ControlName = attrib.Element("ControlName").ValueTrim(),
                            Property = attrib.Element("Property").ValueTrim(),
                            PropertyValue = attrib.Element("PropertyValue").ValueTrim()
                        }).ToList();
```

The file template

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<FormsPersistenceDs>
  <Properties>
    <FormName>Form1</FormName>
    <ControlName>mainNaviBar</ControlName>
    <Property>Width</Property>
    <PropertyValue>275</PropertyValue>
  </Properties>
</FormsPersistenceDs>
```